# What is the meaning of George S Patton's quote "Nobody ever defended anything successfully, there is only attack and attack and attack some more?"

Tags: world-war-two, quotes

George S Patton said that "Nobody ever defended anything successfully, there is only attack and attack and attack some more." What doe this mean?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you looking for context of the quote or an interpretation of what he meant? What research have you done into the quote that may assist in our understanding of what you would like to know?

Comment: I would like an interpretation. I can't really find anything on the quote because it just pops up with a bunch of quote websites that say the quote.

Comment: Just a warning, this may be seen as an opinion based question which will get the question closed. My suggestion would be to word it in another way. Something like, is there any documentation that brings light to what Patton meant when he said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it's difficult to imagine that armies that just defend, without attacking, will win any war. Of course Patton was speaking from the context of having a large materiel superiority, and having numerical manpower advantages. But, stepping back, the quote was meant to instill the spirit of aggression in his armies and perhaps also the home front.

Comment: Patton was also speaking from the context of being an aggressive SOB who competed against his own allies.